# Flex: getting scroll bars on the controls I want and only in viewable area

Tags: apache-flex, layout, scrollbar, flex3

[image: diagram of layout problem]

Flex scroll bars are giving me a really hard time. I want to control exactly which boxes they appear for but after hours of trying random things, my best solution (see below) seems a bit kludgy and unreliable. If I force a scroll bar to appear, (*ScrollPolicy="on") the scroll bar appears disabled, because it spans the entire size of the box, even though that is out of bounds of the viewable area.

I have this one box at the top of the page that runs off the side of that screen, and that's fine--let it run off the side and don't give it a scroll bar. But I have this other box which runs off the side, which is also acceptable, *but* I want scroll bars to serve that region *and* only that region *and* I want those scroll bars to appear in the viewable area. That is, I don't want to have to move the horizontal scroll bar so that it will allow me to see the vertical scroll bar.

---

Now the best I could do is as follows: I found the parent of the main box you see in my diagram (which is actually the great-great-grandparent) that never gets bigger than the viewable area, which is an `mx:Canvas`. Then I force the size of the parent of the box containing my stuff down to the size of the parent `mx:Canvas`, which then causes the scroll bars to appear where I want. So, it's something like:

```
<mx:Canvas id="main_canvas" width="100%" height="100%">
```

*a lot of other tags that are parents*

```
  <mx:Box width="100%" height="100%" maxHeight="{main_canvas.height}" maxWidth="{main_canvas.width}"> <!--box containing the box that should show scroll bars-->
    <mx:Box width="100%" height="100%"> <!--box that should show scroll bars-->
```

*the rest of the tags*

The above tags are an abstraction, btw. Due to the enormous number of experiments I've conducted trying to get the scroll bars where I want them, there's a very tall hierarchy of `mx:*Box`es, `mx:Canvas`es and even an `mx:VDividedBox`.

It seems to work, but it's probably needlessly complicated, and I have a feeling that customers will find a way to make it fail.

I'm using the 3.5 SDK.

Comment: Thanks, guys, but I already gotta Tumbleweed badge :)
But if there's someone wrong w/my question, I'm open to suggestions. I wouldn't even necessarily veto edits.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the best I could do was wrap whatever I wanted to have scrollbars in an `mx:Canvas` and then set its `maxWidth` to a parent component's `width` that is limited to the width I want, and finally put an `mx:Box` inside the `mx:Canvas`. At least, that seemed to work in most cases when controls are vertically stacked and I want a horizontal scrollbar to span the whole width of that `mx:Canvas`. Usually this was enough and somehow the vertical scrollbar issue sorted itself out, but on a couple of occassions, I had to resort to [Flex: getting the height of a collection of controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150111/flex-getting-the-height-of-a-collection-of-controls) to calculate the `maxHeight` of some of the child aggregate controls, which I find a bit kludgy.